# How can I incldue a "private" post type in a loop for public users?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, pre-get-posts, private

I have a post type that I've registered using `"public" => false, "publicly_queryable" => true`, because I don't want singles, but I do want these posts to show up on a custom taxonomy archive. With `"public" => false`, I can't get the posts to appear in the loop on the custom taxonomy archive.

I've tried searching for a solution to this, but I keep coming across "include public and private posts in loop," which isn't exactly what I'm looking for, as I still want the user to be able to set these posts to "private" if they desire.

How can I include a private post type in a loop using the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the query?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, it was simpler than I expected.

```php
/**
 * Include catalog posts in archives, even though they're not "public"
 *
 * @param WP_Query $query
 * @return WP_Query
 */
function wpse415668_catalog_posts_in_archives(WP_Query $query): WP_Query {
    if (! $query->is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_tax("catalog_category")) {
        $query->set("post_type", "catalog");
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter("pre_get_posts", "wpse415668_catalog_posts_in_archives");
```